# Germany Blue Card surname change after wedding

Tags: germany, blue-card, working

I am a BlueCard holder and been working in Germany for 6 months now and I have a wedding in 3 months.

Wedding will not be in Germany, it will be in my home country. After marriage, my surname will change and I will renew my passport with new surname.

My BlueCard was not given in a card form, it is just a sticker in my passport.

After surname change, can I enter Germany and continue to work with my old and new passport and official international documents that shows marriage information? Or should I apply to German Consulate in my country to transfer the BlueCard to my new passport before entering Germany?

Comment: Getting a Apostilled version of your marriage certificate in your own country would be a good idea and will be needed in Germany later anyway (Name change, taxes etc.). Togeather with both passports there should be no problem. Since the residence permit is issued in Germany, the Consulate probably won't be able to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, usually in case of passport change you can still travel with both passports for some time. Of course, change of surname makes things slightly more complicated. In your case, I would write an email to border control asking if they will let you into the country.

Another option might be that you do the name change and passport later in the consulate of your home country in Germany.

Besides this, I suggest that your passport does not become invalid right after you changed your name. However, for this you should check the law of your country. If it stays valid, then you can change your surname in your home country and then travel just with old passport (and change it later in the consulate).

Comment: The consulate of my home country in Germany also advised to change my passport and ID in Germany. I will email border control, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

To get a qualified answer you should ask the authorities directly. You could do so on multiple channels via https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/de/ueber-das-portal/kontakt/

I’m pretty sure that you could use both passports for a grace period with regards to the blue card. But you should nevertheless ask.